# Hidden variable Password parameter - powershell 4.0

Tags: powershell, variables

I am creating a release definition with a powershell script to replace a file with env variables from the release definition it works but It doesn't seem to catch the password variable which is hidden in the release definition. is there a way to tell powershell to look for hidden variables?

**UPDATE:** Here is the script it finds all the variables in `$paramsFilePath` that are not hidden my password in In environmental variables in Release definition is hidden and the script doesn't find it.

```
param(
    [string]$paramsFilePath,

)

Write-Verbose -Verbose "Entering script Replace-SetParameters.ps1"
Write-Verbose -Verbose ("Path to SetParametersFile: {0}" -f $paramsFilePath)

# get the environment variables
$vars = Get-ChildItem -path env:*

# read in the setParameters file
$contents = Get-Content -Path $paramsFilePath

# perform a regex replacement
$newContents = "";

$contents  | % {
    $line = $_
    if ($_ -match "__(\w+)__") {
        $setting = Get-ChildItem -path env:* | ? { $_.Name -eq $Matches[1] }
        if ($setting) {
            Write-Verbose -Verbose ("Replacing key {0} with value from environment" -f $setting.Name)
            $line = $_ -replace "__(\w+)__", $setting.Value
        }
    }
    $newContents += $line + [Environment]::NewLine
}

Write-Verbose -Verbose "Overwriting SetParameters file with new values"
Set-Content $paramsFilePath -Value $newContents



Write-Verbose -Verbose "Exiting script Replace-SetParameters.ps1"
```

Comment: Share your piece of code and then let us know what r u trying to achieve

Comment: Updated my question

Comment: M from mobile. I will check it and update you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike the normal variable, the password you are trying to get is secret variable.

> **Secret Variables**
>
> We recommend that you make the variable Secret  if it contains a
>   password, keys, or some other kind of data that you need to avoid
>   exposing.

The variable replacement we do is **on the inputs on the tasks**, we don't parse the scripts. To use secret variables you will have to take those as inputs into your script we **explicitly do not populate those into the environment**.  You could take a look at this discuss: [Use hidden / secret variables in commands](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/388)

Comment: Hi, i Went on a different road i am using Replace Tokens Task now. But i have the same problem all the variables get passed but the hidden does not.